# Comparator for Optional<T>

Tags: java, generics, guava

I have `abstract class OptionalComparator<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Comparator<Optional<T>>`

So far, so good.

Following the model used by Optional itself, I figured it would be best to have a single instance of this class, and cast it when necessary (for example, to `OptionalComparator<Integer>`).

So I made `private static final OptionalComparator<? extends Comparable<?>> ABSENT_FIRST`.

The trouble came when I tried to assign a value.  What should the type be?

`new OptionalComparator<Comparable<Object>>() {...}` doesn't work.

`new OptionalComparator<Comparable<Comparable<Object>>>() {...}` doesn't work.

`new OptionalComparator<Integer>() {...}` does work, for example, but I want the least-specific type possible.

What am I doing wrong?  How can I make a base-case instance of this class?

Comment: `Object` does not implement `Comparable<Object>` so you cannot use it.

Comment: So is there anything I can use?  Or do I just have to make a new comparator every time I want an instance?

Comment: Well currently it requires a type `T` which implements `Comparable<T>`. I don't fully get what you're trying (plus haven't used these comparators much), but it might be possible if you change the required type argument to something else.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can have multiple implementations of `OptionalComparator` like this:

```
private static final OptionalComparator<? extends Comparable<?>> ABSENT_FIRST = new AbsentFirst<>();

private static final OptionalComparator<? extends Comparable<?>> ABSENT_LAST = new AbsentLast<>();

private interface OptionalComparator<T extends Comparable<T>> extends Comparator<Optional<T>> { }

private static class AbsentFirst<T extends Comparable<T>> implements OptionalComparator<T> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Optional<T> obj1, Optional<T> obj2) {
        if (obj1.isPresent() && obj2.isPresent()) {
            return obj1.get().compareTo(obj2.get());
        } else if (obj1.isPresent()) {
            return -1;
        } else if (obj2.isPresent()) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}

private static class AbsentLast<T extends Comparable<T>> implements OptionalComparator<T> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Optional<T> obj1, Optional<T> obj2) {
        if (obj1.isPresent() && obj2.isPresent()) {
            return obj1.get().compareTo(obj2.get());
        } else if (obj1.isPresent()) {
            return 1;
        } else if (obj2.isPresent()) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}

static <T extends Comparable<T>> OptionalComparator<T> absentFirstComparator() {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    OptionalComparator<T> comp = (OptionalComparator<T>) ABSENT_FIRST;
    return comp;
}

static <T extends Comparable<T>> OptionalComparator<T> absentLastComparator() {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    OptionalComparator<T> comp = (OptionalComparator<T>) ABSENT_LAST;
    return comp;
}

public static void main(String... args) {
    OptionalComparator<Integer> absentFirstInt = absentFirstComparator();
    System.out.println(absentFirstInt.compare(Optional.of(1), Optional.empty()));

    OptionalComparator<Integer> absentLastInt = absentLastComparator();
    System.out.println(absentLastInt.compare(Optional.of(1), Optional.empty()));

    OptionalComparator<Double> absentFirstDouble = absentFirstComparator();
    System.out.println(absentFirstDouble.compare(Optional.of(1.0), Optional.empty()));

    OptionalComparator<Double> absentLastDouble = absentLastComparator();
    System.out.println(absentLastDouble.compare(Optional.of(1.0), Optional.empty()));
}
```

Output:

```
-1
1
-1
1
```

Comment: Not bad, but I was hoping to have two implementations, one for absent-first and one for absent-last.  Is there a good way to do that using this strategy?

Comment: @codebreaker, absent-last could extend this and just have `compare(obj1, obj2) {return -1 * super(obj1, obj2); }`

Comment: @codebreaker I updated the answer showing how to do two implementations. Please check if that's what you need.

Comment: Nice, after I saw your post I realized I could do something like this.  It seems weird, though, when you do `new AbsentFirst<>()`, what are the inferred type parameters?  It doesn't seem like it's possible to explicitly declare them.

Answer (score 10):

Guava now provides (since 21.0, and no more [@Beta](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/annotations/Beta.html) since [27.1](https://github.com/google/guava/releases/tag/v27.1)) [`Comparators`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Comparators.html)`.emptiesLast(Comparator)` and `emptiesFirst(Comparator)`.

Example: `Comparator<Optional<Instant>> compareOptInst = Comparators.emptiesLast(Comparator.naturalOrder());`

Comment: Since Guava 24.0 methods' signatures have slightly changed and now you don't required to use type hinting: `Comparator<Optional<Instant>> compareOptInst = Comparators.emptiesLast(Comparator.naturalOrder());` or even more concise if using static imports: `Comparator<Optional<Instant>> compareOptInst = emptiesLast(naturalOrder());`

Comment: @YooryN. Thanks, I have simplified the example.

Answer (score 2):

You may just have to do an unsafe cast.  Consider how [`ImmutableList`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/src-html/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html) handles the empty-list case:

> ```
> private static final ImmutableList<Object> EMPTY =
>     new RegularImmutableList<Object>(ObjectArrays.EMPTY_ARRAY);
>
> /**
>  * Returns the empty immutable list. This set behaves and performs comparably
>  * to {@link Collections#emptyList}, and is preferable mainly for consistency
>  * and maintainability of your code.
>  */
> // Casting to any type is safe because the list will never hold any elements.
> @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
> public static <E> ImmutableList<E> of() {
>   return (ImmutableList<E>) EMPTY;
> }
> ```

In this case, it might similarly be easiest to use a raw type instance.  As long as you gate all calls that return `ABSENT_FIRST` with generic casts, this will be fine, and calling code shouldn't have any warnings.

Comment: I did realize I could use a raw instance, but I was under the impression raw types could always be avoided.  Furthermore, this causes the method to be of type `int compare(Object o1, Object o2)`, which requires further casting.

Comment: Unfortunately raw types cannot always be avoided, particularly when developing library-type code like you're describing.  If you look through the Guava codebase you'll see quite a lot of `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` annotations - Guava does the unsafe calls so you (normally) don't have to.

Comment: Which isn't to say there's no way to avoid the raw type, but sometimes you know better than the compiler :)