# Comparator for Optional<T> with key extractor, like java.util.Comparator.comparing

Tags: java, lambda, collections, option-type, comparator

Consider the following example where we are sorting people based on their last name:

```
public class ComparatorsExample {

    public static class Person {
        private String lastName;

        public Person(String lastName) {
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Person: " + lastName;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person p1 = new Person("Jackson");
        Person p2 = new Person("Stackoverflowed");
        Person p3 = new Person(null);
        List<Person> persons = Arrays.asList(p3, p2, p1);
        persons.sort(Comparator.comparing(Person::getLastName));
    }
}
```

Now, let's assume that `getLastName` returns an optional:

```
public Optional<String> getLastName() {
    return Optional.ofNullable(lastName);
}
```

Obviously `persons.sort(Comparator.comparing(Person::getLastName));` will not compile since `Optional` (the type `getLastName` returns) is not a comparable. However, the value it holds is.

The first google search points us in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29570443/6579265). Based on this answer we can sort persons by doing:

```
List<Person> persons = Arrays.asList(p3, p2, p1);
OptionalComparator<String> absentLastString = absentLastComparator(); //type unsafe
persons.sort((r1, r2) -> absentLastString.compare(r1.getLastName(), r2.getLastName()));
```

My question is, **is it possible to have this kind of sorting using a function (key extractor) just like Comparator.comparing?**

I mean something like (without caring absent values first or last):

```
persons.sort(OptionalComparator.comparing(Person::getLastName));
```

If we look into [Comparator.comparing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-), we see the following code:

```
public static <T, U extends Comparable<? super U>> Comparator<T> comparing(
        Function<? super T, ? extends U> keyExtractor) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(keyExtractor);
    return (Comparator<T> & Serializable) (c1, c2) -> {
        return keyExtractor.apply(c1).compareTo(keyExtractor.apply(c2));
    };
}
```

I tried multiple ways to make it return an `OptionalComparator` instead of a simple `Comparator`, but everything I tried and made sense to me was unable to be compiled. **Is it even possible to achieve something like that?** I guess type-safety cannot be achieved, since even Oracle's `comparing` throws a type-safety warning.

I am on Java 8.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`Comparator#comparing(Function,Comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing(java.util.function.Function,java.util.Comparator)):

> Accepts a function that extracts a sort key from a type `T`, and returns a `Comparator<T>` that compares by that sort key using the specified `Comparator`.

Here's an example based on the code in your question:

```java
persons.sort(comparing(Person::getLastName, comparing(Optional::get)));
```

Basically this is using nested key extractors to ultimately compare the `String` objects representing the last names. Note this will cause a `NoSuchElementException` to be thrown if either `Optional` is empty. You can create a more complicated `Comparator` to handle empty `Optional`s<sup>1</sup>:

```java
// sort empty Optionals last
Comparator<Person> comp =
    comparing(
        Person::getLastName,
        comparing(opt -> opt.orElse(null), nullsLast(naturalOrder())));
persons.sort(comp);
```

If you need to do this a lot then consider creating utility methods in a manner similar to `Comparator#nullsFirst(Comparator)` and `Comparator#nullsLast(Comparator)`<sup>1</sup>:

```java
// empty first, then sort by natural order of the value
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> Comparator<Optional<T>> emptyFirst() {
  return emptyFirst(Comparator.naturalOrder());
}

// empty first, then sort by the value as described by the given
// Comparator, where passing 'null' means all non-empty Optionals are equal
public static <T> Comparator<Optional<T>> emptyFirst(Comparator<? super T> comparator) {
  return Comparator.comparing(opt -> opt.orElse(null), Comparator.nullsFirst(comparator));
}

// empty last, then sort by natural order of the value
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> Comparator<Optional<T>> emptyLast() {
  return emptyLast(Comparator.naturalOrder());
}

// empty last, then sort by the value as described by the given
// Comparator, where passing 'null' means all non-empty Optionals are equal
public static <T> Comparator<Optional<T>> emptyLast(Comparator<? super T> comparator) {
  return Comparator.comparing(opt -> opt.orElse(null), Comparator.nullsLast(comparator));
}
```

Which can then be used like:

```java
persons.sort(comparing(Person::getLastName, emptyLast()));
```

---

<sup>1. Example code simplified based on suggestions provided by [@Holger](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing(java.util.function.Function,java.util.Comparator)). Take a look at the edit history to see what the code looked like before, if curious.</sup>

Comment: (1+) This helped me a lot. I adjusted it to work with my "existing" optional comparator which handles the "value not present" case. I added my own answer, but I do not know which one I will accept. Thanks anyway.

Comment: It looks inconsistent to mix ternary operators and `if` statements this way. You could use a concise expression lambda syntax if you only use ternary operators. But, on the other hand, you could easily use `public static <T> Comparator<Optional<T>> emptyFirst(Comparator<? super T> comparator) { return Comparator.comparing(o -> o.orElse(null), Comparator.nullsFirst(comparator)); }` using the same semantics as `nullsFirst` (passing a `null` comparator means “only move empty optionals to the front”).

Comment: @Holger Personally I disagree that it looks inconsistent, but maybe I'm missing something. To use _only_ ternary operators would that not require nested ternary operators? Because I find nested ternary operators to be much worse than mixing `if` and ternary operators. The other option was to have three `if` / `else` blocks, which I thought looked overly verbose. In any case, I edited my answer to utilize your `nullsFirst` / `nullsLast` suggestion—it makes the code much smaller (though perhaps slightly more difficult to understand for someone new to comparators).

Comment: If you don’t like nested ternary operators, you could have used `(o1, o2) -> o1.isPresent() && o2.isPresent()? comparator.compare(o1.get(), o2.get()): Boolean.compare(o1.isPresent(), o2.isPresent())` instead.

Comment: @Holger Interesting :) Though I think I would still prefer my original code over that ternary operator—but that could just be familiarity bias.

Answer (score 1):

[Slaw's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61682080/6579265) helped a lot and based on his answer I got exactly what I wanted. However, as he mentions

```
persons.sort(comparing(Person::getLastName, comparing(Optional::get));
```

will throw exception if a value of an `Optional` is not present. By that, we are missing most of the `OptionalComparator` point-sense. But luckily it can be converted to:

```
persons.sort(comparing(Person::getLastName, absentFirstComparator()));
```

where the case of a not present value will be handled.

Also, these two methods can be created:

```
public static <T, U extends Optional> Comparator<T> absentFirst(Function<? super T, ? extends U> keyExtractor) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(keyExtractor);
    return (Comparator<T>) (c1, c2) -> absentFirstComparator().compare(keyExtractor.apply(c1),
            keyExtractor.apply(c2));
}

public static <T, U extends Optional> Comparator<T> absentLast(Function<? super T, ? extends U> keyExtractor) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(keyExtractor);
    return (Comparator<T>) (c1, c2) -> absentLastComparator().compare(keyExtractor.apply(c1),
            keyExtractor.apply(c2));
}
```

and finally I get exactly what I want by:

```
persons.sort(absentLast(Person::getLastName));
```

Comment: The need to perform unchecked type casts should tell you that you are doing things wrong. `U extends Optional` refers to the *raw type* `Optional`, without declaring that the encapsulated value must be `Comparable`.

Comment: Edited my answer based on [suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61681709/comparator-for-optionalt-with-key-extractor-like-java-util-comparator-compari/61682080?noredirect=1#comment109182567_61682080) from @Holger, if you want to take a look. The new code also shows how to fix the NPE problem that [ernest_k's now-deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61682353/6395627) had.

Answer (score 0):

If Google [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) 22.0 or later is already on board then the available [emptiesFirst](https://javadoc.io/static/com.google.guava/guava/22.0/com/google/common/collect/Comparators.html#emptiesFirst-java.util.Comparator-) and [emptiesLast](https://javadoc.io/static/com.google.guava/guava/22.0/com/google/common/collect/Comparators.html#emptiesLast-java.util.Comparator-) comparators are specially designed for Optionals.

```
import static com.google.common.collect.Comparators.emptiesLast;
import static java.util.Comparator.comparing;
import static java.util.Comparator.naturalOrder;

persons.sort(comparing(Person::getLastName, emptiesLast(naturalOrder()));
```

Last names are compared by [String.compareTo(otherString)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo-java.lang.String-) and [empty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#empty--) values are sorted to the end of the list.

Note: Under the hood `emptiesFirst` and `emptiesLast` decorators unwrap the `Optional<T>` to `T` and delegate to JDK's [nullsFirst](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#nullsFirst-java.util.Comparator-) and [nullsLast](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#nullsLast-java.util.Comparator-) resp. comparators.